# Java-How to auto move window in Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a little problem with my program: I want to get auto-moving window in time
I have a code:

```
package simpleFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Trololo
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
         {
            public void run()
            {    

               JFrame frame = new SizedFrame();
               frame.setUndecorated(false);
               frame.setTitle("SizedFrame");
               frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
               frame.setVisible(true);
                   System.out.println("About to schedule task.");
    new ReminderBeep(5);
    System.out.println("Task scheduled.");

            }


         });
   }
}

class SizedFrame extends JFrame
{
   public SizedFrame()
   {
      Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
      Dimension screenSize = kit.getScreenSize();
      int screenHeight = screenSize.height;
      int screenWidth = screenSize.width;
      setSize(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2);
      setBounds(500,500,screenWidth/2,screenHeight/2);
   }

}



 class ReminderBeep {
  Toolkit toolkit;
  java.util.Timer timer;


  public ReminderBeep(int seconds) {
    toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    timer = new java.util.Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds * 1000);
  }


  class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
      SizedFrame window = new SizedFrame();
    public void run() {
         window.setBounds(900,900,500,600);
      toolkit.beep();
      System.out.println("ok");

    }
  }}
```

I have a timer which works: it's showing "ok" in command prompt but window dont moving :/ How to get works?

Comment: Use `javax.swing.Timer` to handle Swing tasks, such as moving the frame. Also, when you adjust the bounds, your heirarchy is invalidated. From the documentation of [`invalidate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#invalidate()): *This method is called automatically when any layout-related information changes (e.g. setting the bounds of the component, or adding the component to a container)*. You must `revalidate()` after setting the bounds of your component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main() method, you create a SizedFrame and display it. You then start a timer.

When the timer fires, you create another SizedFrame, but you don't display it. You then set the bounds on the non-displayed SizedFrame. You aren't resizing the SizedFrame that you're showing.

Comment: Presumably by calling the setVisible(false) method.

Comment: Why not moving/resizing the existing JFrame?

Comment: @keuleJ I agree with you. I'm just answering the questions that OP is asking.

Comment: becouse i'm starting programing and dont know how to do this :x Can i ask You to tell me how move old Jframe? 
Greeting

Answer (score 0):

You have to respawn your form (panem/frame) by refreshing the tem^late , drawing it back (revalidate )and like this it s gonna move